# What mean a column in zero in confusion matrix?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, confusion-matrix

When training my model and reviewing the confusion matrix, there are completely zero columns for each specific category, what does this mean, is there an error or how do I interpret it?

I use the confusion matrix display function and it gives this result

[image]

Thanks for your answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the plot is correct, it means the model never gives any predictions label of 1 and 2.

Comment: Do you have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Can be a lot of reasons - Model overfit/underfit, class imbalance, or simply manual error. From your matrix, label 1 and 2 have fewer samples, so class imbalance would be the 1st thing I look at.

Comment: BTW, @alexm's answer is more comprehensive than mine, worth reading.

Answer (score 2):

The entry $[i, j]$ in a confusion matrix is the number of times the class $j$ was predicted while the correct class was $i$.

For example, $C[1, 1]$ is the number of times your model correctly predicted class $1$. On the other hand, $C[1, 2]$ is the number of times your model predicted $2$ when the correct answer was $1$.

In your case, the entries in $C[1, i]$ and $C[2, i]$ are $0$ for any $i$, which means that your model never predicts classes $1$ and $2$.